# Heroku, Flask and Bokeh

Tags: flask, heroku, bokeh

#### Hi all,

My Flask script is working fine on localhost, however on Heroku server the Bokeh interactive gridplot is not displayed, and I think I have no error message in the logs to start with. (response 200 and 302 which seems correct to me), I am stuck on this error. Does any one have an idea ? 
*Thank you very much. I hope my post is not too messy.*

I create a gridplot based on two figures (myplot, myhist), then I render them in a template html using script and div.

#### HTML

> {{ script | safe }} 
>   {{ div | safe }}

#### Script:

```
from flask  import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for, session

import os
import sys

from bokeh.embed import components
from bokeh.layouts import gridplot
from bokeh.plotting import figure

import numpy as np

### using bokeh version 2.0.1

SECRET_KEY = xxx

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = SECRET_KEY

yf_period = ['5y']
default_udl = ["DAI.DE"]  # by default value
default_period = "5y"  # by default value


def create_p(x, y1, y2):

    TOOLS = "pan,wheel_zoom,box_zoom,reset,save,box_select,lasso_select"

    r = figure(tools=TOOLS, title="Cumulative Return", x_axis_label = "Time", y_axis_label = "Return")

    r.line(x, y1, legend_label = "Equal weigths", line_width = 2, line_color = "red")
    r.line(x, y2, legend_label = "Adjusted weights", line_width = 2, line_color = "green")

    return r

def create_hist(y1, y2):

    hist_1, bins_1 = np.histogram(y1, bins = int(np.round(len(y1)*0.25,0)))
    hist_2, bins_2 = np.histogram(y2, bins = int(np.round(len(y2)*0.25,0)))

    TOOLS = "pan,wheel_zoom,box_zoom,reset,save,box_select,lasso_select"

    p = figure(title="Distribution Return", tools=TOOLS, background_fill_color="#fafafa")
    p.quad(top=hist_1, bottom=0, left=bins_1[:-1], right=bins_1[1:],
           fill_color="red", line_color="red", alpha=0.5, legend_label = "Equal weigths")
    p.quad(top=hist_2, bottom=0, left=bins_2[:-1], right=bins_2[1:],
           fill_color="green", line_color="green", alpha=0.5, legend_label = "Adjusted weigths")

    return p

@app.route('/', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def home():


    if request.method == "POST":
        # DO STUFF
        session['period'], session['udl_name'] = default_period, default_udl

        return redirect(url_for("result"))

    return render_template("pages/home.html", period_names = yf_period)

@app.route('/result')
def result():


    period = session.get('period', None) 
    udl_name = session.get('udl_name', None)
    try:

        x=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7
            ]
        y1=[0.004626884,
            0.01384386,
            0.028751819,
            0.035215938,
            0.045115703,
            0.043869708,
            0.029449802
            ]
        y2=[0.004626884,
            0.01384386,
            0.028751819,
            0.035215938,
            0.045115703,
            0.043869708,
            0.029449802
            ]

         myplot = create_p(x, 
                                  y1, 
                                  y2 
                                  )
         myhist = create_hist(
                                  y1, 
                                  y2 
                                  )

         p = gridplot([[myplot, myhist]])
         # Embed plot into HTML via Flask Render
         script, div = components(p)
         return render_template("pages/result.html",
                                        script = script, div = div)
    except:
        pass    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    port = int(os.environ.get('PORT', 5000))
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port = port)
```

#### Logs :

> 2020-04-20T15:57:30.755061+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Unidling
>   2020-04-20T15:57:30.757641+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to starting
>   2020-04-20T15:57:46.914016+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
>   2020-04-20T15:57:46.729829+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-04-20 15:57:46 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
>   2020-04-20T15:57:46.730457+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-04-20 15:57:46 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:7796 (4)
>   2020-04-20T15:57:46.730570+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-04-20 15:57:46 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync
>   2020-04-20T15:57:46.734721+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-04-20 15:57:46 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
>   2020-04-20T15:57:46.779520+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-04-20 15:57:46 +0000] [11] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 11
>   2020-04-20T15:57:50.647705+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=ptf-optimizer.herokuapp.com request_id=fcab3952-b3ea-4fce-b2df-51a2d524b1d0 fwd="78.194.177.126" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=1774ms status=200 bytes=2006 protocol=https
>   2020-04-20T15:57:50.647433+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.47.187.89 - - [20/Apr/2020:15:57:50 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 1844 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.18362"
>   2020-04-20T15:57:50.781574+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.47.187.89 - - [20/Apr/2020:15:57:50 +0000] "GET /style/style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 635 "https://ptf-optimizer.herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.18362"
>   2020-04-20T15:57:50.781820+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/style/style.css" host=ptf-optimizer.herokuapp.com request_id=3b3ffe68-a4e2-4313-94de-35278c3069de fwd="78.194.177.126" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=5ms status=404 bytes=803 protocol=https
>   2020-04-20T15:58:01.585246+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/" host=ptf-optimizer.herokuapp.com request_id=fa983e78-f32c-44ac-87ce-1d1c189b245c fwd="78.194.177.126" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=5ms status=302 bytes=579 protocol=https
>   2020-04-20T15:58:01.585048+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.47.187.89 - - [20/Apr/2020:15:58:01 +0000] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 302 221 "https://ptf-optimizer.herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.18362"
>   2020-04-20T15:58:01.682864+00:00 app[web.1]: loading BNP.PA
>   2020-04-20T15:58:01.913560+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   2020-04-20T15:58:01.977549+00:00 app[web.1]: Doing some stuffs
>   2020-04-20T15:58:02.241402+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/result" host=ptf-optimizer.herokuapp.com request_id=ab5a90cb-c427-40e3-801f-97fb08be4d71 fwd="78.194.177.126" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=556ms status=200 bytes=30750 protocol=https
>   2020-04-20T15:58:02.235865+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.47.187.89 - - [20/Apr/2020:15:58:02 +0000] "GET /result HTTP/1.1" 200 30573 "https://ptf-optimizer.herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.18362"

Comment: I use Bokeh 2.0.1 and my Html header is :<head>
 <link
    href="http://cdn.pydata.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-2.0.1.min.css"
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
 <link
    href="http://cdn.pydata.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-widgets-2.0.1.min.css"
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
 <link
    href="http://cdn.pydata.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-tables-2.0.1.min.css"
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

 <script src="http://cdn.pydata.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-2.0.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://cdn.pydata.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-widgets-2.0.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

Comment: Would you mind linking your `requirements.txt` file? I'd like to deploy it myself to see if I can correct my answer below.

Comment: requirements.txt >bokeh==2.0.1
certifi==2020.4.5.1
chardet==3.0.4
click==7.1.1
cycler==0.10.0
Flask==1.1.2
gunicorn==20.0.4
idna==2.9
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.11.2
kiwisolver==1.2.0
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
matplotlib==3.2.1
multitasking==0.0.9
numpy==1.18.3
packaging==20.3
pandas==1.0.3
Pillow==7.1.1
pyparsing==2.4.7
python-dateutil==2.8.1
pytz==2019.3
PyYAML==5.3.1
requests==2.23.0
scipy==1.4.1
seaborn==0.10.0
six==1.14.0
tornado==6.0.4
typing-extensions==3.7.4.2
urllib3==1.25.9
Werkzeug==1.0.1
yfinance==0.1.54

Comment: Do you have an `environment.yml`? I'm seeing some results talking about having to install NodeJS as well in the `environment.yml` for it to successfully deploy on Heroku.

Comment: I only have requirements.txt, and PROCFILE web: gunicorn myflask_app:app

Comment: Sorry I couldn't be more help. Maybe this link could be relevant: https://discourse.bokeh.org/t/deploy-bokeh-flask-app-on-heroku-i-tried-everything-possible-with-no-success/4585/7

Answer (score 0):

Is the program trying to read/write directly from Heroku's filesystem? If I'm reading it right, that may be the issue.

Heroku does not have a filesystem that you're allowed to read/write to. If you need to store data, you have to use a DB or the Env variables.

Comment: normally not. i do not read/write file. It i simple, on first page(home) I ask 2 variables that are stored through flask.session and I retrieve them on the second page (result) through session.get(). I have removed the lines  ```output_file(os.path.join(ptf_opt.output_path, filename + ".html"), title ="Cumulative Return", mode = 'inline')``` ``` output_file(os.path.join(ptf_opt.output_path, filename + "_hist.html"), title ="Histogramme Return", mode = 'inline') 
``` as they are not used and I reran, same issue on Heroku. My goal is not to use DB, because I want to keep it simple.

Comment: It looks like `output_file()` from the `bokeh.plotting` module is trying to save a file, but it can't because of Heroku's file system. You may need to find a new way to store that output.

Comment: ``output_file()`` is actually not used. I removed it. Same issue. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved my issue. I needed to replace my bokeh ressources from hardcoded links in my html templates and use instead `bokeh.ressources`

```
    <script src="http://cdn.pydata.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-2.0.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.pydata.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-widgets-2.0.1.min.js"></script>
```